# Uninstall net bean 8.0

Tags: netbeans

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rbrC.png)

Trying to uninstall but it is no working,
Close NetBeans and any associated processes.
Go to the "Control Panel" on Windows or "Applications" on macOS.
Find "NetBeans 8.1" in the list of installed programs or applications.
Click on "Uninstall" or "Remove" for NetBeans 8.1.
Follow the on-screen instructions to complete the uninstallation process.
Once the uninstallation is finished, restart your computer if prompted.
tried different step nothing works